# android.support.v7.internal.app layout rendering

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, rendering

I use mac os and Android Studio 1.4.1. Few days ago I created projects without any problems. 
Today, when I tried to make new project i got error.
[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRJMy.jpg)
 <- Rendering problem in layout file.
I know, that I can change in style.xml this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

and in some way it will solve the problem cuz error will be gone. But when i change it, I cant see my actionbar in layout file.
I checked dependencies, there is -v7 app compat in 23.1.1 version. Also in activity file there is import support.v-7.app.appCompatActivity
I have second laptop with windows and I tried to copy sdk from windows to mac (on win works perfectly) but there was another problems.
I know I can live with that but I dont like when something is missing and I dont know why. And interesting is that, i reinstall Studio, SDK and there is still the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered this issue too. To fix it, I changed this in my build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

So this small update of AndroidStudio bring new library and it spoiled everything.
Thank you very much for help